# Ripple effect problem: not reaching edges

Tags: css, keyframe

I am currently trying to create a CSS ripple effect. When I scale the button the ripple don't reach the edges of the button. The speed of the growth of the ripple is the same for every button size. It is a regular button. The CSS is added when the button is pressed.

This is my CSS code:

```
            position: absolute;
            background: #000;
            border-radius: 50%;
            width: 5px;
            height: 5px;
            animation: ripple 0.88s linear;
            opacity: 0;
            pointer-events: none;

            @keyframes ripple {
                from {
                    transform: scale(1);
                    opacity: 0.4
                }
                to {
                    transform: scale(100);
                    opacity: 0;
                }
            }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you include the html as well?

Comment: It is a regular button. This CSS is added when the button is pressed.

Comment: Then please include that in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Separate the ripple effect from the button element. Use a span element to execute the animation. Like so:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('button').on('click',function(){
    $(this).find('.ripple').remove();
    $(this).append($('<span class="ripple"></span>'));
  });
});
```

```css
button{
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100px;
  height: 25px;
}

button.big{
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
}

button.bigger{
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
}

.ripple{
  position: absolute;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  animation: ripple 0.88s linear;
  transform: scale(1);
  
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}

@keyframes ripple {
  from {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 0.4
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(100);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="">Ripple!</button>
<button class="big">Ripple!</button>
<button class="bigger">Ripple!</button>
```

Keep in mind that, since you're scaling to a 100x size, the biggest buttons your effect will support is a little under 500px wide (because of the ripple's borders)